# Populate a list with objects of a class

Tags: c#, list

I am currently making a game with randomly generated rooms, as I iterate through the newly created rooms to check their coordinates to add them onto a graph I have a list of rooms.

```
list<Room> listOfAllRooms;
```

I can continue with the clunky way of specifying where all the room objects are stored.

```
list<Room> listOfAllRooms = new List<Room> {roomObject.room1, ...}
```

They are stored in another class just to keep things tidy, exactly like so...

```
public class RoomObjects { public static Room room1 = new Room(); .....}
```

All the way for 25 rooms.

This is messy beyond all belief and will create a serious issue should I expand beyond the current 25 rooms I am currently working with.
In my mind there should exist a way to populate this list of all the rooms directly from one neat and tidy source.
So really my question boils down to is there a better way to declare these objects and store them into a list automatically? or if not at least a way to add each room into a list automatically?

(Note, I have a large part of the code working with a list of all rooms so i hope i don't have to re-write that to fix this)

Comment: I would suggest you to use `ObservableCollection<Room>` instead of `List<Room>` would be easier.

Comment: What if you provide a method in that class that can add the instances to a list and return that list?

Comment: why not use list instead of `room1`,`room2`,`room3`....?

Comment: Why do you use static rooms adding them to a non-static list? Why do you need every single room seperately?

Comment: you want to populate your class RoomObjects or list<Room>?

Comment: this list is being used to check variables on start, I'm still new to C# so maybe there is a better way. @StepUp I'd like to populate a list with objects created elsewhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Room` class:

```
public class Room
{
    public string NameRoom { get; set; }
}
```

To create objects of Room class, it is possible to use pattern `Factory Pattern`. With this pattern, we develop an abstraction that isolates the logic for creating of class to create. The pattern has really simple implementation, see:

```
public static Room FactoryOfRoom(string roomName)
{
    return new Room() { NameRoom=roomName };
}
```

And this code is where you can populate your list by `Factory Pattern` pattern:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   List<Room> listRoom = new List<Room>();
   for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
   {
       listRoom.Add(FactoryOfRoom(i.ToString()));
   }       
}
```

If it is not what you want, feel free to correct me.

Comment: Wow, Thank you... I hadn't even thought of the idea to use logic for the creation of the rooms, This is a perfect solution.

Comment: @Grey read more about patterns:). It is real treasure of programming world. For example, the best book I've ever read is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns and this link is very helpful https://csharpdesignpatterns.codeplex.com

Comment: I appreciate the codeplex link to design patterns in C#4. I didn't come across this yet :)

Answer (score 0):

Though not elegant solution but in your case using reflection until the time we refactor or change design, we can prepare list of available rooms suppose in case `room1, room2` etc., were used at many places directly instead of using from `List<Room>` but the new code using `List<Room>`.

I emphasize that this is just to show alternate possibility:

```
public class RoomObjects 
{
   public static Room room1 = new Room { Id = 1 }; 
   public static Room room2 = new Room();
   public static int room3 = 0; //Took int type for test that Room & Int32 type castings don't mess up while reflecting

   public List<Room> GetRoomObjects()
   {
       List<Room> availableRooms = new List<Room>();

       var allRoomFields = this.GetType().GetFields(); //GetProperties() in case of properties we want to reflect over.

       foreach (var roomFieldInfo in allRoomFields)
       {
           Room tempRoom = roomFieldInfo.GetValue(this) as Room; //Here Int32 field won't throw invalid cast exception while casting to Room type

           if (tempRoom != null)
           {
               availableRooms.Add(tempRoom);
           }
       }

       return availableRooms;
   }
}
```